# How can I keep users logged in for periods of time

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

I have a database containing usernames and passwords... I can understand how to check if the user has entered a valid username and password when they click a login button but how can I keep them logged in for periods of time.. For example I only have to login to Facebook like once every 4 months. I'm assuming cookies have something to do with it? Anyone have some advice or clarity of thought to offer? I don't want to make my users log-in every time they try to view a page :) ahha!

Comment: What do you believe about `Sessions` and `Cookies`. Are you not fully clear with them?

Comment: I'm completely new to the internet scene. I've only programmed using Actionscript 2 and Objective-C up until this point... So I know nothing about any of this PHP and MySQL stuff ahha! Eager to learn though!

Comment: In actionscript we could store data on a users computer using something called "SharedObject" do you know of it, or if it is similar to cookies? They were pretty easy to use but users could go find the file we saved the info to (usually titled name.sol) and open them in a text editor to see some of the data (luckily, most was encrypted automatically by flash)

Comment: You need to start by learning basic in which you're interested most and what is this term `"ahha!"` you're using here? Sounds like an alien language.

Comment: Sorry I don't know about `SharedObject`, since I'm working mostly with enterprise Java and mobile applications.

Comment: I'm bad at typing "haha" ahha!

Comment: @Dharman Why was this question from 2011 flagged as a 'duplicate' of a question from 2018 which has less activity and less answers than this one?

Comment: It looked like it has a better answer. If you don't agree you can suggest a better one and I can swap it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a user enters their username and password into a form in your site, validate the username and password to be correct, and then set a `$_SESSION` data for the user's id for starters. Then, on page load, check if the `$_SESSION` data is set or not, and if it is, the user is logged in.

Also, if you're storing passwords, you **should** hash them up and salt them up and store the hashed passwords.

**Some links and tutorials on Hashing**

http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html

http://seanmonstar.com/post/707158385/a-basic-lesson-in-password-hashing

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/rainbow-hash-cracking.html

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/i-just-logged-in-as-you-how-it-happened.html (read through codinghorror.com 's stuff. Very well written)

Comment: Can you explain what hashing and salting is? I have read little on hashing in the past when I was reading about a website that got hacked... I have no knowledge on the subject though and I like to learn o:)

Comment: Please check the updated answers for a few links you should read up before you even start storing passwords. I urge you to go through them and find the most secure methods to store passwords. :)

Comment: Okay, thanks! Will those sites also show me how to use the $_SESSION function?

Comment: No they won't. But you can easily find sites that'll show you how to build a login area within your website. It's fairly simple provided you take the security precautions. Search google for "php login tutorial" and you'll have plenty :)

Comment: I always forget about google at times like this haha! Thankyou! 
You should have posted a lmgtfy url I love those! Here's one: http://bit.ly/tjWrPq

Answer (score 3):

There are two durable methods of carrying variables. Sessions and Cookies. Sessions store user data on the server until they expire, and Cookies store data on the user's computer. Both sessions and cookies have variable periods that they last (though it's easier to set cookie expirations), but you should read up on both:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As you assumed cookies is the best option. Keeping a session for a long period is not a good idea.

You can store user's information in cookies. For more security you can encrypt them before saving. May be with base64_decode()

As an example see bellow code.

```
setcookie("USER",$userName,time()+ (3600 * 24 * 30 * 4));
setcookie("PWD", base64_encode($password),time()+ (3600 * 24 * 30 * 4));
```

Good luck.

Prasad

Comment: I'm curious would I really need to store the password in the cookie or could I just store a variable saying the date the last successfully logged in with their valid password? Also after I use setcookie how do I check it later? Is checking a cookie on every page going to be slow in which case a session might be faster? Thanks for all the help so far guys!

Comment: Hi You can get Cookies from using following way.

$refNo = $_COOKIE["USER"];
$userName = $_COOKIE["PWD"];